# How to get field from django model by name from list

Tags: python, django, list, model

I got model like:

```
class mymodel(models.Model):
    val1 = models.FloatField(default=0)
    val2 = models.FloatField(default=0)
    ...and more var with other names
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I need change values in many models but not all fields (only from list)

```
list= ['val1', 'val2' .... 'val15']
for entry in list:
    mymodel.entry = data[entry]
```

How can i do it?  i tried {entry}, entry, [entry]

Comment: What is `data`, a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with [**`setattr`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) to set an attribute. This thus means that `setattr(x, 'y', z)` is equivalent to `x.y = z`, so you can work with:

```
mylist = ['val1', 'val2' .... 'val15']
for entry in mylist:
    setattr(mymodel, entry, data[entry])
```

beware that `mymodel` here should be a model *object*, not the *class*, since otherwise you are destroying the fields defined on the class, and not creating records at the database.